# I can't commit a file to GitHub, and there is no error messenge

Tags: bash, git, github, git-bash

I already have the repo in GitHub set up, but when I try to push a file from my local machine to the remote repo it just doesn't work, I don't even get a error message, my terminal just stops responding.

[[image: the window get wen trying to push a text fileto my GitHub repo]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run `git status` to determine what's going on.

Did you commit the files you are trying to push?

You can check out Github's tutorial at the following [link](https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/).